# how to update the image?

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel-5.8

I want to edit the picture, but it doesn't work. What is the syntax for editing a picture?

I tried the following in the controller:

```
 public function edit($id)
    {
        $makan = Gambar::find($id);
        return view('edit_upload',['makan'=>$makan]);
    }
    public function prosesedit($id, Request $request)
    {
        $makan = Gambar::find($id);
        $makan->nama_makanan = $request->input('makanan');

        if($request->hasfile('image'))
        {
            $file = $request->file('file');
            $nama_file = time()."_".$file->getClientOriginalName();
            $tujuan_upload = 'image_file';
            $file->move($tujuan_upload,$nama_file);
        }
        $makan->save();
        return redirect(route('makan'));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this

```
public function prosesedit($id, Request $request)
    {
        $makan = Gambar::find($id);



         $nama_file=$makan->file;




        if($request->hasfile('image'))
        {
            $file = $request->file('file');
            $nama_file = time()."_".$file->getClientOriginalName();


            $tujuan_upload = 'image_file';
            $file->move($tujuan_upload,$nama_file);
        }
        $makan->update([
         'file'=>$nama_file
]);
        return redirect(route('makan'));
    }
```

Comment: <div class="form-group">
                    <b>File Gambar</b>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="file" name="file" value="{{ $makan->image_file }}">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <b>Nama Makanan</b>
                    <br/>
                    <input type="text" name="makan">
                </div>

Comment: where is your route to post this form

Comment: this is the route Route::get('/makanan/edit/{id_makanan}', 'MakananController@edit');
Route::post('/makanan/prosesedit/{id_makanan}', 'MakananController@prosesedit')->name('prosesedit');

Comment: i said the full form of this blade